# Limiting number of paths the query search in cypher query other than limit

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want the query to stop as soon as it finds first 10 paths and return those.
But by default the limit clause finds all the paths and then just returns first 10 paths.
Because total paths in my case will be around 10k to 20k, its not practical to do that.
i tried following two queries which dont work

```
match path = (first:Job)-[:PRECEDES*]->(last:Job)
where first.name = 'xyz' and last.name = 'abc'
return nodes(path) as pathlist

match path1 = (first:Job)-[:PRECEDES*]->(middle:Job)
where first.name = 'xyz' 
with middle, path1
match path2 = (middle:Job)-[:PRECEDES*]->(last:Job)
last.name = 'abc'
return nodes(path1),nodes(path2) as pathlist
```

both are taking forever to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have an index in place:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Job(name)
```

By inspecting the statements using `PROFILE` in neo4j-shell I've found the following being the cheapest variant:

```
 MATCH (a:Job {name:'xyz'}), (b:Job {name:'abc'}) 
 MATCH path=(a)-[:PRECEDES*]->(b) 
 RETURN nodes(path) LIMT 10
```

Please note that I'm talking of Neo4j 2.1.6. Since Cypher's implementation is steadily evolving, a upcoming version might already optimize your statements appropriately.

Comment: Stephan thanks for your effort.I have index in place already. and i tried this query. its taking the same time. Im using 2.1.2, and the thing is limit doesnt stop the query to stop searching after 10 paths, instead it just takes first 10 paths after the query gave all the possible result.(at least that is my understanding). I want the query to give first 10 results and stop searching after that.

Comment: could you paste the profile output of this query in 2.1.2?

Comment: im running it in eclipse. so actually im not getting any out put....i get output when i do this  -->//for(int i = 1; i < 50 ;i++) match path = (b:Job) -[:PRECEDES*"+ i + "]-> (n:Job)