# Limiting the query search in cypher other than limit

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My question 'i think' is the same as a previous Stack Overflow question  : [Limiting number of paths the query search in cypher query other than limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183614/limiting-number-of-paths-the-query-search-in-cypher-query-other-than-limit)   - which I don't think was sufficiently answered.

I would like the example code to search only until it has found the first 10 results -- NOT to find all results and return the last 10.
Update - Added the WITH statement.

```
WITH [ 'animalia','illustrated','childrens','book' ] as nodes
MATCH (p:Entity)--(m:Entity)
WHERE p.name in nodes
WITH m, size(nodes) as inputCnt, count(DISTINCT p) as cnt
WHERE cnt = inputCnt
RETURN m limit 10;
```

The above Cypher query finds nodes with entries that are common to all inputs.
I want to make this code as fast as possible as it is a search kernel for my application. If I am not mistaken,as written it will search the graph and return the first 10 results.    How do i get it to simply stop the search once the first 10 results are found ?

Comment: There are some things missing here. `nodes` isn't defined, and there's nothing to indicate that it is a parameter. Also you cannot parameterize a label, so `(m:$entity_title)` isn't valid.

Comment: Updated the example as per the comment by InverseFalcon1

Comment: Can you explain what you are ultimately trying to achieve with the `cnt = inputCnt` test? It is not obvious.

Comment: In a word - intersections - I based this code on what I saw here: https://community.neo4j.com/t/know-more-on-intersection-cyphers/3343    Per m node, we're getting the count of distinct a nodes that are connected to that m node, and that count needs to be equal to the size of the input collection. If so, that means all of the values in the input are connected to that m node (provided there aren't duplicate values in the input collection).

Comment: Your query's `cnt = inputCnt` test, in the context of the preceding `WITH` clause, does not indicate that ALL the values in `nodes` are used in `p` nodes connected to a particular `m`. For instance, that test would be satisfied even if all 4 related `p` nodes have the same `name` value.

Comment: You have to change `count(DISTINCT p)` to `count(DISTINCT p.name)` to perform the test you intended.

Comment: Thanks Cybersam - a more precise query,    but this doesn't answer the question posed? - i.e.  return after the the first 10 results are found  not find all results and return the first 10 ?